# How to select record if "where" conditions are in array

Tags: axapta, x++

Like in title.

I need to select records from InventTable. To do this I want to use seleted ItemId from dynamic array. The question is to build a filter based on values from that array.

Comment: Could you share some code? As far as I can tell from your question, it should be as simple as getting the array value, put it into a ItemId variable and use that variable in the where condition.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is not too big you can use `QueryBuildRange` as follows:

```
static void UseArrayToFilterRecords(Args _args)
{
    str arr[5];
    int i;
    str items;
    Query q;
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
    QueryRun qr;
    InventTable inventTable;

    // Populate the array for test purposes
    arr[1] = '10003';
    arr[2] = '10004';
    arr[3] = '10005';
    arr[4] = '10006';
    arr[5] = '10007';

    // Populate the string to be used in a filter with item numbers from the array
    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        items += items ? ',' + arr[i] : arr[i];
    }

    // Create a query
    q = new Query();
    qbds = q.addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));
    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(InventTable, ItemId)).value(items);

    // Run the query and display result
    qr = new QueryRun(q);    
    while (qr.next())
    {
        inventTable = qr.get(tableNum(InventTable));
        info(strFmt('Item number: %1, Record-ID: %2', inventTable.ItemId, inventTable.RecId));
    }

    info('Job completed');
}
```

Otherwise you can populate another table with the values from your array and join that table and `InventTable` to select only required records.